# Questions regarding javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Sorry that the question is vague, but I'm actually here because I can't put my real question into words, so I can't google it.
This is the part of code I'm working with, I'll ask my questions below:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#accordion0" ).accordion({
            active: false,
            collapsible: true,
            heightStyle: "content"
        });
        $( "#accordion1" ).accordion({
            active: false,
            collapsible: true,
            heightStyle: "content"
        });
        $( "#accordion2" ).accordion({
            active: false,
            collapsible: true,
            heightStyle: "content"
        });
        $( "#accordion3" ).accordion({
            active: false,
            collapsible: true,
            heightStyle: "content"
        });
    });
</script>
```

1. What is the $( "#accordion0" ) called? I know that "#accordion0" refers to the id of the element.
2. Am I right in calling the ".accordion" the class?

Then on to what I'm actually trying to do:
How do I combine the code so I don't have a 4x duplicate of code.

And a second less related question, is there a site that lists all the options for these jquery ui widgets (eg: "active: false). I looked around to find many individual examples, but not a full list.

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/ for more information about accordion

Comment: Thanks Anton. I've actually had that page open this whole time, but I guess I didn't see the blatantly obvious until now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is referred to as the selector. You are creating a jQuery object from the element you are selecting.

```
$('#ID')
```

This would work:

```
$("#accordion0, #accordion1, #accordion2, #accordion3").accordion({...});
```

You could also add a class to each of the elements in question, and then select the class instead of each ID individually.

```
$('.accordionClass').accordion({...});
```

There are lots of resources available on using jQuery selectors.

For example: [W3Schools - jQuery Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)

Comment: Follow the link to find out how inept and useless w3schools are.

Comment: @LeeTaylor , if the information on the jQuery selectors is accurate, I find no problem not to use it as a reference point.

Answer (score 5):

> What is the $( "#accordion0" ) called? I know that "#accordion0"
>   refers to the id of the element.

It is a jQuery method that selects the DOM elements based on the selector. The DOM elements are wrapped in a jQuery object so you can use chaining. [Learn about jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) to understand how to use it. No one can explain it here on stackoverflow for you.

> Then on to what I'm actually trying to do: How do I combine the code
>   so I don't have a 4x duplicate of code.

Use a common class that all of the elements share. If the common class on the elements is `class="accordion"`, your code would use a class selector like the following.

```
 $( ".accordion" ).accordion({
        active: false,
        collapsible: true,
        heightStyle: "content"
    });
```

> And a second less related question, is there a site that lists all the
>   options for these jquery ui widgets (eg: "active: false). I looked
>   around to find many individual examples, but not a full list.

And the jQuery UI Docs would be the place to look.
    http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: Ah, perfect. When I tried this earlier, I mistyped it as "#.accordion" instead of ".accordion".

Answer (score 0):

The `#accordionN` is the element your're interacting with... the `#` lets you know that `accordionN` is the ID of the element.

`.accordion` is the jQuery method you're applying to said element(s).

To apply the method to all four *without* changing the code, just add in each element ID to the selector:

```
$('#accordion0, #accordion1, #accordion2, #accordion3').accordion({
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a common class all those #accordionX have like:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( ".accordion" ).accordion({
            active: false,
            collapsible: true,
            heightStyle: "content"
        });
    });
</script>
```

It should do the trick, not seeing your html structure i can't be more precise.

1)What is the $( "#accordion0" ) called? I know that "#accordion0" refers to the id of the element.
What do you mean ? $( "#accordion0" ) is the selector
2)Am I right in calling the ".accordion" the class?
.accordion is not a class but a function call.

Answer (score 0):

First off, the dollar sign is creating a variable, so if you call $("#accordion0"), you're creating JQuery a variable with the element of id accordion0.  This tells JQuery that you're ready to do stuff with an element.

Second.

You could do one of two things.  You could give them all a class variable, let's say "someVar" and do this:

```
$(".someVar").command("foo");
```

Or you could

```
$("#accordion1, #accordion2",.....).command("bar");
```

Here's an example.

http://jsfiddle.net/ynmEZ/

also

http://api.jquery.com/ - should be of use

Answer (score 0):

1) "#accordion0" is called a jquery selector. You use selectors to select certain DOM element.

2) ".accordion": this is a selector for the class accordion.

You could use a selector like this:
$("[id^=accordion]").accordion({ ... });

Check [this site](http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/jquery-selectors), or maybe google for jquery selectors.